# Declaring JS variables using for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, scope

When I declare a variable by `let` keyword more than one time with the same variable name, I know it is showing an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'variable name' has already been declared`.

For example (1)*:

```
let v = "1";

let v = "1";
```

But when I declare many variables with the same name in a loop, I do not know why it is not showing the same error.

For example (2)*:

```
for(let i = 0; i<=2; i++){

    let v = "1"

}
```

Already I know there is a logical explanation for it but I do not know what

**Note: Assume that Declaring the first two variables in example(1) in JS file, and creating the loop in example(2) in another JS file**

> This question has been answered before but it was deleted by mistake so I repost it with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration of the loop is a new scope.

Like when you declared variable with  `v` name regardless of it is value in `global scope` and declare a variable with  `v` name in `if statement` scope, The program will not show any errors because two variables are not in the same scope

for example :

```
//glopal scope
let v = "1"
console.log(v) // output : 1

//if statement scope
if(true === true){
 let v= "2"
 console.log(v) // output : 2
}

//also in global scope after if statement scope 
console.log(v) // output : 1
```

So the same situation is happen with the loop because Each iteration of the loop is a new scope.